# Error running make all in makefile

Tags: bash, shell

Makefile:

```
all: my1 my2 my3 my4
s2: s1
    tr "1" "2" < s1 > s2
    chmod u+x s2
s3: s1
    tr "1" "4" < s1 > s3
    chmod u+x s3

prog.cpp : i1 i2 i3
    cat i1 >  prog.cpp
    cat i1 >> prog.cpp
    cat i3 >> prog.cpp

prog2.cpp: prog1.cpp
    tr "1" "2" < prog1.cpp > prog2.cpp

prog3.cpp: prog1.cpp
    tr "1" "3" < prog1.cpp > prog2.cpp

prog4.cpp: prog1.cpp
    tr "1" "4" < prog1.cpp > temp
    sed 's/READY/NOT READY/' temp > prog4.cpp

prog1.o: prog1.cpp
    g++ -c prog1.cpp
prog2.o: prog2.cpp
    g++ -c prog2.cpp
prog3.o: prog3.cpp
    g++ -c prog3.cpp
prog4.o: prog4.cpp
    g++ -c prog4.cpp

my1: prog.cpp
    s1
my2: prog.cpp
    s2
my3: prog.cpp prog1.o prog2.o prog3.o prog4.o
    g++ -o prog prog.cpp -D_d3 prog1.o prog2.o prog3.o prog4.o

my4: prog.cpp   
    s3

clean:
```

[image]

when I try to run my make all command, it gives the error. I've been at the program for over 2 hours and cannot figure out why! Any help/ideas? 
i1 i2 i3 are simple text files and s1 is a bash script.

Comment: the error msg says `s1: Command not found`. I don't see anything in your make file that creates an `s1` file. Is that supposed be in your project dir, or in your PATH. Or are you missing a step in your make file that will create an `s1` object. (Years since I did much with `make` so I have have forgotten a basic make tenent, and this whole comment is wrong-headed). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The last file in my directory is s1 (below prog1.cpp). I just assumed that make would look in the directory for s1 when it needs it. Should I call s1 in makefile (how?) ?

Comment: sorry, I missed that. (I always sort my dir listing w `ls -ltr` to see the newest created files at the bottom. (That might help you here)). Weird that you're getting that error msg. Do you have any `cd` cmds in your makefile? Otherwise I'm out of ideas. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: @shellter nope, no cd cmds. Also, I'm using g++ compiler for c++ files here. Do I have to install gcc for this to work? Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `.` is not in `PATH`. You could add `.` to `PATH`, or call `./s1` in the makefile.